# Trait not registered - Rspec - Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have this folder structure:

```
.
  spec
    factories
      category.rb
      service.rb
```

But when I call category from service, I get `Trait not registered` error, because `category.rb` is not loaded before `service.rb`.

I suppose to write this in service:

```
require_relative 'category'
```

would work, however is there a simpler way to do this, because I would have to `require_relative` in each file and several times in each file, since each model has many associations.

## Update

I can't do what I mentioned in my last paragraph:

```
require_relative 'category'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :service do
    category
  end
end
```

results in:

```
Factory already registered: category (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError)
```

Comment: you will need to show some code, because referencing factories from within each other is perfectly fine.

Comment: hmm, my problem is not referencing factories, let me update.

Comment: You don't need to `require_relative 'category'`. Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: because when I don't do that, I get  `trait not registered`. But seems that's solved now... what do you think could be the problem. Seems that `require_relative` fixed things because I did not do anymore than that, strange thing is I removed it... well.

Comment: Did you really mean to say that your factories were under the `specs` directory or did you mean `spec`?

Comment: You aren't defining any traits in the code you have shown, so you would not get a 'trait not registered'. Is there more code and a proper error, that you aren't showing?

Comment: there is another thing I have not mentioned.. and that could be the cause, I am using zeus, I will restart it.

Comment: hmm that's the problem, I forgot about it because I rely it was reloading environment when a change happened, but seems there are some cases in where code is not reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not mentioned in my question, so this answer could not be deduced from my question, I post to complete.

Problem was I am using zeus server, I restarted zeus server and things worked.

Answer (score -1):

The solution, which is also a better practice in my opinion, is to put all of the factories into one file, instead of separate ones.

Actually we don't need too much factories files if the factories are not too much.

Move all of the definition in to `spec/factories.rb`, and then remove the directory and files `spec/factories`.

Comment: The best practice aside, do you have reason to believe that having all the factory definitions in a single `factories.rb` file produces different results than having them in separate files under `factories`?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, there is no difference except we don't need to consider `require` and factory dependency any more. I think this is simple and easy to debug.

Comment: So you think there's a difference in dependency consideration when the definitions are in separate files? My understanding is that all the factory files are loaded at once when FactoryGirl starts up and no evaluation of the included blocks (including inter-factory references) takes place until all the files are loaded, meaning that there is no difference in the dependency consideration introduced by the way in which the definitions are spread across multiple files.

Comment: I supposed the same... but, then what could be my problem? It happened again.